# Dynamically create list of list based on index - Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I am trying to make a giant result list with lists of list based on index. I can't predefined how many lists will be inside of the giant list.

```
id   value
1     30
1     21
1     12
1     0
2     1
2     9
2     14
3     12
3     2
4     3
5     1

result = []
for id, dfs in df.groupby('id'):
    ....

    for i, row in dfs.iterrows():
        x = helper(row[value])
        # If the list is found, append the element
        if (result[i]):
            result[i].append(x)
        # Dynamically make lists base on index
        else:
            result[i] = []
```

If the list already defined, then just append the value x in the list.

Expected Output:

```
    first index      second index  third index   fourth index
[[x1,x5,x10,x11,x14], [x2,x4,x9], [x3,x7],       [x20]]
```

x values are compute by the helper function

Comment: How do you find if the list is already created or not? By list name?

Comment: Yes by the list name @mad_

Comment: You can create a recursive function for this

Comment: x is a value, it can't be the name of the list. I want the name of the list contains the index @mad_

Comment: Without input excepted output is void. Edit your post to make it clear

Comment: @mad_ added more input output description

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me if you want the result as a dataframe or dict with the 'index' as keys or just as a list with the items in the right order. *Btw, Python lists start with index `0`.*

```
In [706]: result = collections.defaultdict(list)
     ...: for id, dfs in df.groupby('id'):
     ...:     result[id].extend(list(dfs['value'].values))
     ...:

In [707]: result  # this will be a dict
Out[707]:
defaultdict(list,
            {1: [30, 21, 12, 0], 2: [1, 9, 14], 3: [12, 2], 4: [3], 5: [1]})

In [708]: [result[k] for k in sorted(result.keys())]  # turn it into a list
Out[708]: [[30, 21, 12, 0], [1, 9, 14], [12, 2], [3], [1]]
```

If you want to apply some operation to each item in the group, like you're doing with `helper()`, you can do:

```
In [714]: def helper(val):
     ...:     return 'x' + str(val)  # simplifying whatever helper does

In [715]: result = collections.defaultdict(list)
     ...: for id, dfs in df.groupby('id'):
     ...:     result[id].extend(map(helper, dfs['value'].values))  # pass each value to helper

In [716]: result
Out[716]:
defaultdict(list,
            {1: ['x30', 'x21', 'x12', 'x0'],
             2: ['x1', 'x9', 'x14'],
             3: ['x12', 'x2'],
             4: ['x3'],
             5: ['x1']})

In [717]: [result[k] for k in sorted(result.keys())]
Out[717]:
[['x30', 'x21', 'x12', 'x0'],
 ['x1', 'x9', 'x14'],
 ['x12', 'x2'],
 ['x3'],
 ['x1']]
```

Note that `result[id].extend(...)` is not actually needed since each group of values for that `'id'` will be passed in together. So you don't need to check if that `id` already exists in result. It could have been just:

```
In [720]: result = collections.defaultdict(list)
     ...: for id, dfs in df.groupby('id'):
     ...:     result[id] = list(map(helper, dfs['value'].values))
```

---

Ideally, you'd want to create `helper` so that it can be used with [`pd.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), by operating on all the `dfs` rows together.

Or even better, build `helper` so that it can do something with the the dataframe of each `groupby` result, via [`pd.groupby.GroupBy.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).